# Grep for multiple strings, show number of lines after one of the strings (but not the other)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I would like to search a file for multiple strings and for one particular string, show the 5 lines following it as well.

```
cat file | grep -e 'string1' -e 'string2'
```

works of course, but I would like to get something like

```
cat file | grep -e 'string1' -e -A 5 'string2'
```

How can I make it so that (I'm assuming using the -A 5 option) it shows only the lines containing string1 and only the lines containing string2 and the 5 lines after string2, but not the 5 lines after string1?

EDIT: just got it working with awk:

```
cat file | awk '/string1/{c=1}/string2/{c=5}{while(c-->0){print;getline}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

about awk code

```
awk '/string1/ {if ( c <= 0 ) c = 1;} /string2/ {c=5} { if (c-- > 0) print; }' file
```

- do not `cat ... | awk`, awk can read file.
- I rearrange test (if string1 is one line after string2, it interrupt printing in OP's solution)

Comment: To much `if`s… `awk '/string2/{c=NR+5}/string2/,NR==c{print;next}/string1/'`

Comment: Your shorted variant is `awk '/string2/{c=4;do{print;getline}while(c--)}/string1/'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using one go of `grep`. You need to use two `grep` instances :

```
grep 'string1' file; grep -A 5 'string2' file
```

If you want to run the second upon success of the first one :

```
grep 'string1' file && grep -A 5 'string2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sed** solution:

```
sed -n '/string2/,+4{p;b;};/string1/p' file
```

my `sed` also accept `~` instead of `+`